# Submitting a Spark application to the virtualbox Spark Master

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera

I have created a Spark application Hello World that works well locally through Eclipse IDE.
I would like to deploy remotely this application from my local machine to the virtualbox Cloudera machine, through the "spark-submit".
The command line used for that is:

```
C:\Users\S-LAMARTI\Desktop\AXA\Workspaces\AXA\helloworld\target>%SPARK_HOME%/spa
rk-submit --class com.saadlamarti.helloworld.App --master spark://192.168.56.102
:7077 --deploy-mode cluster helloworld-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Unfortunately, the application doesn't work, and I get this message error:

```
15/10/12 12:20:40 WARN RestSubmissionClient: Unable to connect to server spark:/
/192.168.56.102:7077.
Warning: Master endpoint spark://192.168.56.102:7077 was not a REST server. Fall
ing back to legacy submission gateway instead.
```

Can someone have any idea, why is not working?

Comment: Is your master IP correct? If its a single VM both Spark UI and master should get started on 192.168.56.1, it seems like its unable to connect to 192.168.56.102

Comment: @mbaxi, I've just updated the content of this question. I tried the --deploy-mode cluster option, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Does following command gets executed successfully "spark-shell --master spark://192.168.56.102:7077" ?

Comment: It doesn't work. The message error is: 15/10/12 12:39:18 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sp
arkMaster@192.168.56.102:7077/user/Master...
15/10/12 12:39:18 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote syste
m [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@192.168.56.102:7077] has failed, address is now gated
for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].

Answer (score 0):

Remove the arguement `--deploy-mode cluster` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the master:8080,and then you can see two url,one is the client submit url,another is the rest for cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Find your REST url, if you set the argument `--deploy-mode cluster`, you must set the argument `--master spark:Rest url`.